# Using the picamera function start_recording with threading on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Trying to thread image acquisition on the raspberry pi 3 using the picamera. Original programmer to write this code disappeared so I have to brush up on python again and I'm kind of lost. Right now I'm just trying to do something very basic and hope to expand from it.

Am I doing this right?

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from threading import Thread

class myCamrecord(self):
    def __init__(self,resolution=(1280,720),framerate=45,RecLen=5):
          self.camera = PiCamera()
          self.camera.resolution = resolution
          self.camera.framerate = framerate
          self.Reclen = RecLen

    def RecordVideo(self)
          self.camera.start_recording("testvid.h264",foramt="h264", quality=23)
          self.camera.wait_recording(Reclen)
          self.camera.stop_recording()


ReVid = myCamrecord()
Camthread1 = Thread(ReVid.recordvideo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [threading document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=thread#thread-objects), after creating Thread object, its start method should be call so that the new thread can run. You also need to provide None as the place holder for unimplemented group feature. So the code will be as below.

```py
Camthread1 = Thread(None, ReVid.recordvideo)
Camthread1.start()
```

or

```py
Camthread1 = Thread(target=ReVid.recordvideo)
Camthread1.start()
```

Comment: This worked. thanks. just missing the _target=_ can crash the whole thing.